# Why are you starting this bounty? - does it matter for views count?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, bounty-remarks

I have started bounty offering 200 points of my hardly earned reputation ;-)

[iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0 blending with Cocos2D gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735542/cocos2d-ccrendertexture-alpha-opacity-blending-problems)

All I want is the question to be answered but the question is quite specific (not widely applicable).
The natural choice for me was: **"Draw attention"**. Is this the good choice in this situation? 
I was also considering **"Authoritative reference needed"** because of the nature of the question.

What are the differences (up or downsidess, if any) between those 2 options?

Answer (score 11):

The difference is in what you want the people answering and trying to get the bounty to focus on.

Do you simply want more answers? - use Draw attention.

Do you need authoritative references? use Authoritative reference needed.

---

Whatever you choose, the system treats the same way - it is just displaying a different message as the bounty message.

Comment: Suppose it helps for the backend as well, in some regard. Could SE Staff query/cross-reference how many people are posting bounties for different reasons? This may be usable to evaluate the effectiveness of the way it works.

Comment: @danielhanly.com the bounty reason is not kept anywhere as far as I know, and is lost for good after the bounty is over. Oded, is this true?

Comment: If that is the case, it'd be a shame... though, I'm one of these people that loves statistics and data.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - We do keep it. Mods can see which one was selected in the post timeline.

Comment: Nice, good to know! @danielhanly see Oded's above response. :)

Comment: Oded, why do you think that "Draw attention" means "want more answers" when the description for this reason is "This question has not received enough attention" (which I think is quite vague)?